# How can I keep the original jar without .original suffix?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-maven-plugin

I just created a `user-jar` with `quarkus-maven-plugin`.

```xml
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.quarkus.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
              <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>uber-jar</quarkus.package.type>
                <quarkus.package.main-class>${mainClass}</quarkus.package.main-class>
                <quarkus.package.output-directory>${project.build.directory}</quarkus.package.output-directory>
                <quarkus.package.runner-suffix>-quarkus</quarkus.package.runner-suffix>
              </properties>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>uber-jar</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>build</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

The the plugins renames the original jar file with `.original` suffix.

```
$ ls -1 target
...
some-x.y.z-SNAPSHOT-quarkus.jar
some-x.y.z-SNAPSHOT.jar.original <<<<<<<<
...
$
```

How can I keep the original jar file without `.original` suffix?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following code,

```java
    /**
     * When the building an Uber JAR, the default JAR is renamed by adding {@code .original} suffix.
     * Enabling this property will disable the renaming of the original JAR.
     */
    @Deprecated
    @Parameter(property = "skipOriginalJarRename")
    boolean skipOriginalJarRename;
```

Not sure why it's been deprecated.

Comment: Just for the record, deprecation discussed here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34388 And now there is a more sofisticated way to achieve this behaviour. https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling#uber-jar-maven

Comment: @zforgo Would you please given me some configuration solves what I want? I came from the same link you posted. Thanks.